# Why $(< file.txt) don't work on makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

Using the command line I get the desired output

```
 $ ./program $(< file.txt)
 ./program 1 2 3 4 5
```

But with a makefile

```
all: program file.txt
    ./program $(< file.txt)
    @rm -f program
    
program: program.c
    gcc program.c -o program
```

I get the output

```
gcc program.c -o program
./program
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in a makefile, the `$(...)` syntax is used for variable interpolation. So your makefile tries to expand the value of a makefile variable / environment variable named `< file.txt`. And if unset, it expands to an empty string.

Proof:

```
all:
        echo $(< file.txt)
```

and file.txt containing

```
now it works
```

Then execute

```
% env '< file.txt=Hello world' make
echo Hello world
Hello world
```

i.e. by setting an environment variable named `< file.txt` to value `Hello world` , the greeting was printed. The fix is to escape the `$` character by doubling it:

```
all:
        echo $$(< file.txt)
```

and then

```
% make
echo $(< file.txt)
now it works
```

Q.E.D.

Finally, while the `$()` interpolation syntax in POSIX **shells**, the `$(< file.txt)` is not but you can replace it with `$(cat file.txt)` so it works with minimally POSIX-conforming shells. Of course in a makefile you again need to double the dollar, therefore getting the maximally compatible

```
$$(cat file.txt)
```

Alternatively you can use the similar makefile facility which is `$(shell )`, i.e.

```
 $(shell cat file.txt)
```

would work too... (now with one `$`). Finally you can read files with `$(file )` GNU makefile function too, i.e.

```
all:
        echo $(file <file.txt)
```

would work alike but wouldn't call shell at all.

Comment: shouldn't it be
all:
        echo $$(file <file.txt) at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The substitution you are trying to use is a Bash feature, but `make` out of the box runs the regular Bourne shell `sh`, where this syntax is not available (even when `sh` is a symlink to Bash, as is still common on some Linux distributions).

Requiring the contents of the file to be specified on the command line looks like a design flaw, anyway; it's probably much better if your C program simply reads and processes standard input (or perhaps accepts a list of file names, and falls back to stdin if none are specified, like many Unix file processing utilities).

If this is just for a test case to run the program with parameters from a file, check out `xargs`.

```sh
xargs ./program <file.txt
```

If you insist on using Bash-only syntax, add

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

(or whatever full path is correct on your system); but understand that this limits the portability of your `Makefile`.

Still, you'll need to double any literal dollar sign which should be passed through and exposed to the shell.

Comment: Also, you need to use `$$(< ...)` not `$(< ...)`

Comment: This is already mentioned in the last sentence; is it not clear enough?

Comment: Or just use `./program $$(cat file.txt)` instead of `./program $$(< file.txt)`. `xargs ./program <file.txt` is NOT an equivalent to either of those.

Comment: I see.  It was buried away a bit at the bottom :).  It is the primary issue that the OP has; the use of bash syntax is only secondary because that syntax isn't even being seen.

Comment: POSIX requires that [`/bin/sh` supports `$()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), that's not a bashism. Any system that doesn't allow for that is `POSIXLY_INCORRECT`

Comment: the direction is not supported, but you can replace *that* with cat.

Comment: No one suggested that `$(...)` was a bashism.